# android google maponClick not responsive

Tags: android, dictionary, onclick

I have a map in my layout which when clicked should addmarker to it and display it on map.But the onMapClick method is not triggered when clicked.Below is the code":
Details.java:

```
public class Details extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener {
   SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
   private GoogleMap map;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.details);
       mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map1);
       mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

   }
   @Override
   public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
      map=googleMap; LatLng bolg = new LatLng(9.984616,76.267082);
         map.addMarker(newMarkerOptions().position(bolg).title("Demo")).showInfoWindow(); map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(bolg));
      map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(7), 3000, null);
      map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

   }
   @Override
   public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
      Log.e("LongClick","clicked");
      map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("X")).showInfoWindow();
      map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
      map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(7), 3000, null);
      map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
   }
}
```

details.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/map1"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment">
    </fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To detect user click event on GoogleMap, modify the AppCompatActivity
>   implements OnMapClickListener, override onMapClick(LatLng point), and
>   call map.setOnMapClickListener(this).

```
map.setOnMapClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your onMapReady set an on click listener map.setOnclicklistener

Answer (score 1):

After getting google map from mapfragment you need to do the following for receiving click events.

```
GoogleMap mGoogleMap = mapFragment.getMap();
mGoogleMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
```

you need to implement this listener also `GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener`